# connect pushbuttons to lineedits

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a problem with my python code, it's a QTablewidget with Qpushbuttons and Qline_edits inside each cell, We want a file path (after selecting this file from the file browser) to be written in the line edit when we click on its pushbutton and to store the output files so we can use them after.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QFileDialog,
    QGridLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QTableWidget,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sys
from functools import partial
global list_C
list_C=[]
class boxlayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(boxlayout,self).__init__()
        layout=QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        boxlayout.le=QLineEdit()
        boxlayout.btn=QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(boxlayout.le)
        layout.addWidget(boxlayout.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        mainlayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.resize(640, 480)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setRowCount(4)
        mainlayout.addWidget(self.table)
        save_button=QPushButton('OK')
        mainlayout.addWidget(save_button)
        save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_as_list)
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                self.table.setCellWidget(i,j, boxlayout())
                boxlayout.btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.open_dialog, boxlayout.le))


    @pyqtSlot(QLineEdit)
    def open_dialog(self, le: QLineEdit):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Open File",
            "${HOME}",
            "All Files (*)",
        )
        le.setText(file_name[0])

    def save_as_list(self):
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                item=self.table.cellWidget(i,j).le.text()
                list_C.append(item)  
        print(list_C)   #output=['last le value','last le value',...]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_gui = Main()
    main_gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: could you provide the code, please?

Comment: @Ameya  it's added to the question now

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ניר  I don't know what is the Minimal, Reproducible Example (it's the first time I'm seeing this term) but I think it should produce a runnable code, right?. If that so, I don't think I can't do it because I don't know what to put in the uploadfile method, it's empty

Comment: @fz159753 Hi and welcome, It means that we should be able to copy your code and run it and then reproduce what was your problem.

Comment: About your problem. It sounds like you want a thing that is very specific to your code, You should make your problem as general as possible so that even someone who does not know anything about your code would know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QFileDialog,
    QFrame,
    QGridLayout,
    QLineEdit,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sys
from functools import partial

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        top_frame = QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(top_frame)
        self.grid = QGridLayout(top_frame)
        for i in range(10):
            btn = QPushButton(top_frame)
            le = QLineEdit(top_frame)
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.open_dialog, le))
            btn.setText("open file system dialog")
            self.grid.addWidget(btn, i, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(le, i, 1)

    @pyqtSlot(QLineEdit)
    def open_dialog(self, le: QLineEdit):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Open File",
            "${HOME}",
            "All Files (*)",
        )
        le.setText(file_name[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_gui = Main()
    main_gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The key thing here is to pass the `QLineEdit` to the file selector method.
Here we are doing it with: `lambda: self.open_dialog(le)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked but there is a slight problem: when I click on any Qpushbutton and chose the file the file_name is always written in the last Qline_edit and not the one in front of the clicked Qpushbutton

Comment: Oh let me fix that real quick.

Comment: Use `functools.partial` instead of a `lambda`. Updated post.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, Thank so so much

Comment: Hello, I'm stuck again :/ can you please help me, my problem is when I use the le  (QLineEdit) outside the method open_dialog  it gets only the value of the last cell even if I specify the desired one with the code self.tableX.cellWidget(row,col).le.text() @ניר

Comment: @mc159753 where do you call it?

Comment: in another method: after filling all the line_edits  I click on a button connected to a method that save all the line_edits output in a list, the problem is that i get a list filled only with the last record of the lineedit @ניר

Comment: @mc159753 Sorry, I can't understand you. Please update your code with the relevant code or open a new question..

Comment: I updated the code :D @ ניר

Comment: Just create a list in `__init__` and in `open_dialog` append to that list the file names.

Comment: This is what i did first and it worked, but this will create a false list if i choose a file in one of the qlineedits and then realize that is not what i want and change it, the list will take both the false file and the next one

Comment: create a condition, If the result is False don't append.